# 3 digits for milliseconds in DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I created a function and it returns a date looks like:
2016-07-15T10:10:52.***031563***+00:00

It's fine but the problem is digits for milliseconds. How to remove the 3 last digits? I only need 3 ones.

```
private function getFormattedDate($time = 'now'){
    $t = microtime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
    $d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
    $d->modify($time);

    return $d->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s.uP'); // note at point on "u"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `u` modifier will always return six digits. [Quoting the manual](http://php.net/date):

> Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.

If you don't want that, you have to manually insert the format you need, e.g.

```
return $d->format('Y-m-d\Th:i:s.') . substr($micro, 0, 3) . $d->format('P');
```

This will then output something like `2016-07-15T12:29:30.546+02:00`

Comment: Shame on me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get 3 digit millisecond value we can now use 'v' format:

```
echo (new datetime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.v');
```

this outputs 3-digit millisecond, no need to use substr.

```
2023-06-04 21:13:50.544
```

Reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php